# Keyboard language doesn't change with alt+shift in Hyper-V VM

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I use Hyper-v Manager 10.0.19041.1. Host: Win10 Pro 21H2, Guest: Win10 Pro 21H2.

I added a few languages, but when I click *alt+shift* to change the language it doesn't work. It does work on the host though.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is a bug. I was able to solve this by just deleting all languages and add them again.